# Replacing \\N with NA using R & data.table OR HIVE

Tags: r, hive, data.table

I have some data in the form:

```
          V1   V2  V3         V4  V5         V6   V7  V8  V9 V10 V11
 1. 14342667 4336 1.5 2015-10-03 \\N 2015-10-03  804 2.0 2.0   0 3.0
 2. 14342667 4336 0.8 2015-06-13 \\N 2015-06-11 2912 2.0 2.0   0 \\N
 3. 14342667 4336 0.5 2016-01-02 \\N 2015-12-27 1618 0.0 0.0   1 \\N
 4. 14342667 4336 0.7 2015-08-22 \\N 2015-08-22 1780 2.0 2.0   0 \\N
 5. 14342667 4336 0.9 2015-02-21 1.2 2015-02-17 1548 0.0 0.0   1 \\N
 6. 14342667 4336 1.0 2015-08-08 \\N 2015-08-06 1538 2.0 2.0   0 2.25
 7. 14342667 4336 0.9 2015-03-28 \\N 2015-03-24 2129 7.0 7.0   0 \\N
 8. 14342667 4336 0.8 2015-04-11 \\N 2015-04-11 2316 1.0 2.0   0 \\N
```

I want to replace instances of `\\N` with NA using R and data.table. I got these in places of blank when I sqooped data into HIVE.

I have tried things like `data1 <- data1[, lapply(.SD, recode, '"\\N"=NA')]` and `data1 <- data1[, lapply(.SD, recode, '"\N"=NA')]` using CAR package which works well for other replacements but failing in the current case with error:

> Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
>     in recode term: "\N"=NA
>     message: Error : '\N' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\N"

I have also read solutions like `x[x=="\\N"] <- NA` but I couldn't lapply those successfully using data.table. I have also looked into HIVE table side solution but apparently `regexp_replace` works only for one column not for all instances in all columns.

Comment: @akrun frank: Thanks for your suggestion and in fact your suggestions complement each other. With akrun's solution doing great for numeric and frank's solution for characters. I have successfully tested akrun's solution but (though logically convincing) there is something amiss in character case in the solution suggested by frank. I am sorry for not dputting data earlier, please find it in following comment.

Comment: @frank here is the dput output for data: structure(list(MDSE_ITEM_I = c(14342667, 14342667, 14342667, 14342667, 14342667, 14342667, 14342667, 14342667), WK_BASE_IDX_Q = c(1.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 0.8), WK_END_D = structure(c(16711, 16599, 16802, 16669, 16487, 16655, 16522, 16536), class = "Date"), SLS_TYPE_GRP_C = c("\\N", "\\N", "\\N", "\\N", "\\N", "\\N", "\\N", "\\N")), .Names = c("MDSE_ITEM_I",  "WK_BASE_IDX_Q", "WK_END_D", "SLS_TYPE_GRP_C"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1c068e8>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find out the columns that have this pattern with `grep` and then use `as.numeric` on those columns

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(df1)[colSums(sapply(df1, grepl, pattern = "\\\\"))!=0]
setDT(df1)[,(nm1):= lapply(.SD, as.numeric) , .SDcols= nm1]
df1
#         V1   V2  V3         V4  V5         V6   V7 V8 V9 V10  V11
#1: 14342667 4336 1.5 2015-10-03  NA 2015-10-03  804  2  2   0 3.00
#2: 14342667 4336 0.8 2015-06-13  NA 2015-06-11 2912  2  2   0   NA
#3: 14342667 4336 0.5 2016-01-02  NA 2015-12-27 1618  0  0   1   NA
#4: 14342667 4336 0.7 2015-08-22  NA 2015-08-22 1780  2  2   0   NA
#5: 14342667 4336 0.9 2015-02-21 1.2 2015-02-17 1548  0  0   1   NA
#6: 14342667 4336 1.0 2015-08-08  NA 2015-08-06 1538  2  2   0 2.25
#7: 14342667 4336 0.9 2015-03-28  NA 2015-03-24 2129  7  7   0   NA
#8: 14342667 4336 0.8 2015-04-11  NA 2015-04-11 2316  1  2   0   NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(14342667L, 14342667L, 14342667L, 14342667L, 
14342667L, 14342667L, 14342667L, 14342667L), V2 = c(4336L, 4336L, 
4336L, 4336L, 4336L, 4336L, 4336L, 4336L), V3 = c(1.5, 0.8, 0.5, 
0.7, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 0.8), V4 = c("2015-10-03", "2015-06-13", "2016-01-02", 
"2015-08-22", "2015-02-21", "2015-08-08", "2015-03-28", "2015-04-11"
), V5 = c("\\\\N", "\\\\N", "\\\\N", "\\\\N", "1.2", "\\\\N", 
"\\\\N", "\\\\N"), V6 = c("2015-10-03", "2015-06-11", "2015-12-27", 
"2015-08-22", "2015-02-17", "2015-08-06", "2015-03-24", "2015-04-11"
), V7 = c(804L, 2912L, 1618L, 1780L, 1548L, 1538L, 2129L, 2316L
), V8 = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 7, 1), V9 = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 7, 
2), V10 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V11 = c("3.0", "\\\\N", 
"\\\\N", "\\\\N", "\\\\N", "2.25", "\\\\N", "\\\\N")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1.", 
"2.", "3.", "4.", "5.", "6.", "7.", "8."))
```

Comment: @Frank That works well with the example I created.  `setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), na.strings = "\\\\N"))]`

Comment: @Frank You could post that as a solution as it is entirely different method.

Answer (score 2):

At @akrun's suggestion, here is another simple way:

```
ccols = which(sapply(DF, class) == "character")
DF[ccols] <- lapply(DF[ccols], type.convert, na.strings="\\\\N")
```

Use `str(DF)` to see that the columns are whatever they should be (numeric or integer).

---

With data.table, this would look like

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
ccols = which(sapply(DF, class) == "character")
DF[, (ccols) := lapply(.SD, type.convert, na.strings="\\\\N"), .SDcols=ccols]
```

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is in Hive inside HDFS looks like `//N` so one can use function `nvl()` for replacement as well if looking for HIVE side solution.